# React Native Android App Build failed in appcenter.ms

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, react-native-device-info

I am trying to build my react native android app using appcenter.ms, but i am getting this error.

```
> Task :react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_372). Please file a bug against the Java 
compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the 
Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the 
following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class 
com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
```

This errot does not occur when i build on my notebook locally, it only fails on appcenter.ms

i have tried updating the lib to **"react-native-device-info": "^10.8.0"** but still the build fails with the same error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

BUILD FAILED in 8m 58s
Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1
 at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af- 
839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
 at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
##[error]Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1
```